# Why the method of log_prob in my Pytorch doesn't work

Tags: python, pytorch

For example, I have a Beta distribution in Pytorch, and the parameter *a*=0.01 and *b*=1.4709.
The density function is as below:
[Density function of the Beta distribution](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FrbJN.jpg)

Then I sample an action from this distribution which is 1.1754943508222875e-38.

Now, there is something happened, after I calculate the *log_prob* of this action, what I get is 81.83833312988281.

We know that the sampled action is extremely small and the probability of this action should be very close to 1. However, the *log_prob* becomes very large and more than 0.

Firstly, shouldn't the *log_prob* be between *[-inf, 0]* ??

Answer (score 4):

log_prob returns the log of the probability density/mass function (pdf) evaluated at the given sample value. Probability density mass is not the same as probability since for a continuous distribution like the Beta distribution  the probability of any single value is actually 0. As such, there's no stipulation that the log-pdf evaluated at a given point should be between [-inf,0].

In fact, for your linked example you can see that the pdf evaluated at  1.1754943508222875e-38 would be extremely large - hence the large positive log_prob value of 81.83833312988281.